# DynamoDB batch_write got throttled even with high throughput

Tags: throughput

Currently I'm experiencing a DynamoDB write throughput issue. I set the write throughput to be 10000 and I have 6 processes that are running batch_write(number of entries to be stored: 500 million+). The average consumed write throughput is very low (around 500) but I still got the writes throttled, and the average number of throttled requests is 800. (all in 5min scale)

I'm wondering why this happens and how I can avoid it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might come from tables partitioning:

As explained [here](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-medium-monitors-dynamodb-performance/), even if you provisioned a certain write capacity for a table (or a Global Secondary Index), the actual request-throughput limit can be much lower. As described by AWS [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions), DynamoDB automatically partitions your tables behind the scenes, and divides their provisioned capacity equally among these smaller partitions.

When some items are requested extremely frequently, they have “hot keys” creating an extremely uneven access pattern. When tables are getting large, they are highly partitioned. For example, if you have provisioned 1000 writes per second for a particular table, and this table is actually split into 10 partitions, then the writes will be throttled at 100 requests per second at best, even if other partitions’ allocated throughput are not consumed a lot.

Which makes this tricky is that the AWS Console does not expose the number of partitions in a DynamoDB table (even if partitioning is well documented). In order to anticipate throttling of hot keys, you can estimate the number of partitions you can expect for a table, using the formula described in the AWS documentation. Then you can calculate the throughput limit of each partition by dividing your total provisioned write capacity by the expected number of partitions.

I hope this helps  :)